# Passing google map into function in html string results in unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I am attempting to pass a google map as a parameter into a function call that is embedded into html defined in javascript like so:

```
var html = "<div id='content'><a href='javascript:takeMeThere("+rectangle.getBounds().getCenter()+","+map+");'>"+rectangleId+"</a></div>";
```

But, this gives me an error of unexpected identifier, where the center coordinates are passed, but the map is just an [object Object] and not identified. The map is a global variable and my takeMeThere function is

```
function takeMeThere(rectCenter, map) {
    map.setZoom(17);
    map.panTo(rectCenter);
}
```

I have tried not including the map as a parameter, since it is a global variable I thought it would use it just fine, but it says setZoom is not a function because it is not recognizing the map at all, but then it won't let me pass it into my function...

Anyone know how I could pass my map through? Basically I want the content of an info bubble (that html string becomes the content) to be clickable, and when clicked will center the user and zoom into the area.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the call to the function look like (where `latLng` is a `google.maps.LatLng` object and `map` is a `google.maps.Map` object):

```
takeMeThere(latLng,map);
// implemented this way:
takeMeThere(new google.maps.LatLng(rectCenterLat, rectCenterLng),map);
```

so the HTML ends up as (creating a new `google.maps.LatLng` object, you could pass in the reference to the `rectangle`, but then it would have to be in the global namespace):

```
var html = "<div id='content'><a href='javascript:takeMeThere(new google.maps.LatLng(" + rectangle.getBounds().getCenter().toUrlValue(6) + "),map);'>" + rectangleId + "</a></div>";
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7p84q9vw/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    map: map,
    bounds: {
      north: 37.442,
      south: 37.44,
      east: -122.14,
      west: -122.142
    }
  });
  var rectangleId = "rectangle";
  var html = "<div id='content'><a href='javascript:takeMeThere(new google.maps.LatLng(" + rectangle.getBounds().getCenter().toUrlValue(6) + "),map);'>" + rectangleId + "</a></div>";
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = html;
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

function takeMeThere(rectCenter, map) {
  map.setZoom(17);
  map.panTo(rectCenter);
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="info"></div>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```